# Video encoding on client side vs server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, encoding, video-streaming

I am very new to this topic and I google searched but wasn't able to find anything concrete.

So, I was going through [this article](https://itnext.io/how-to-make-a-serverless-flutter-video-sharing-app-with-firebase-storage-including-hls-and-411e4fff68fa) where the author says

> In most video workflows there will be a transcoding server or serverless cloud function, that encodes the video into various resolutions and bitrates for optimal viewing in all devices and network speeds.

> If you don’t want to use a transcoding server or API (which can be quite pricey), and depending on the kind of videos your app needs to upload and view, you can choose to forego server side transcoding altogether, and encode the videos solely on the client. This will save considerable costs, but will put the burden of encoding videos on the clients.

> Even if you do use some server-side transcoding solution, you’ll probably want to perform minimal encoding on the client. The raw video sizes (especially on iOS), can be huge, and you don’t want to be wasteful of the user’s data plan, or force them to wait for WiFi unnecessarily.

I am curious to know advantages between encoding video on client side and server side and since HTTPS determine quality based on bandwidth speed (?), Does it have any affect on encoding video on client side?

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever encoded a video on your computer?  It uses a lot of CPU resources. The fan comes on, etc. If you start creating 4-5 different versions of the video on the clients phone, you'll drain BOTH their data plan and their battery.

Using an encoding API to create these variations does cost some money. But - one advantage of using such a service is that you get video experts helping you build the right sizes and resolutions for all of your videos. Some even handle all the hosting and delivery of the videos.

I suppose it depends how far down the rabbit hole you wish to go down. You can build it yourself, but there are many services like [api.video](https://api.video) that can do this work for you

Comment: Please don't forget to add attribution when you link to services you work for.